# How to prevent specific elements to submit inside a form?

Tags: javascript, forms, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuetify.js

I am using vuetify in my vuejs project and i have a v-form with some v-text-fields, v-selects and v-switchs in it.

I have 3 POST methods, one for the text fields and selects, other for one switch and the last POST for another switch.

At the moment i have the problem of when i am doing the POST for the text fields and selects, it sends all the 3 POST methods for all inputs.

Here is my v-form:

```
<v-form
  ref="form"
  v-model="valid"
  lazy-validation
>

// some vuetify elements

<v-form>
```

I call the form refs and then i use vuex to do the POST method:

```
if (this.$refs.form.validate()) {
   //
}
```

I can not put the v-switchs outside the form because the way it is built.

Can someone help to tell me how i can prevent the 2 "v-switch" to activate?

Comment: please show us the the post code (don't need the url but the payload)

Comment: the payload of the switchs is just a boolean and a id like this: payload = [boolean, id] @depperm

Comment: Could you add the code where you do the post please? It's not clear how you're actually posting the data.